# hide posts from users except the logged in user

Tags: php, sql

How can I do

```
WHERE post_status = 1 OR (post_user = $user AND post_status = 0)
```

The news board cannot show posts hidden from other users. Only for the logged in user to choose to make it available or not

```
select * from post
foreach to show $postUserId
```

and below

```
select * from users where user_id = $postUserId
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
INNER JOIN users ON post_user_id = user_id 
WHERE post_status = 1  OR ( post_status = 0 AND post_user_id = $userId )
```

Comment: Shouldn't have values/variables in SQL. Parameterize query and bind in values.